# Why cant my Facebook page be embedded on a website?

Tags: facebook, embed

Im attempting to embed a simple Facebook timeline onto my website, unfortunately when I put the link of the facebook page that I want to embed into the [Facebook page plugin website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/), a preview is not available, and it doesn't appear on my website when I copy the code into my HTML.

It does work when I change the link to something else.

This is the link to my Facebook page:

https://www.facebook.com/flatworlddigital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page does not appear to be fully public, I get

> Sorry, this content isn't available right now

when I follow your Facebook link.

The documentation for the plugin clearly mentions that it won’t work for pages with any kind of privacy restrictions, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/#privacy:

> **Privacy Restricted Pages**
>   Facebook Pages with privacy restrictions cannot be embedded.